# A sort of AM-GM inequality for matrices

Tags: matrices, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $A, B$ be symmetric, positive definite matrices. Is it true that
$$
tr \left( (A B^2 A)^{1/2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{4} \| A + B\|_F^2?
$$
In the diagonal case, the left-hand side is $tr(AB)$ and,
denoting by $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ the diagonal elements of $A$ and $B$, the inequality follows from the usual AM-GM inequality:
$$
tr(AB) =\sum_i \mu_i \lambda_i \leq \frac{1}{4} \sum_i (\mu_i + \lambda_i)^2 = \frac 14 \| A + B\|_F^2.
$$

To convince ourselves that the inequality is true,
we can run the following python code, which prints 0.99999375.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

n, d, ratios = 100000, 3, []
for i in range(n):
    A = np.random.randn(d, d)
    B = np.random.randn(d, d)
    A, B = A.dot(A.T), B.dot(B.T)
    lhs = np.matrix.trace(la.sqrtm(A.dot(B).dot(B).dot(A)))
    rhs = (1/4)*la.norm(A + B, ord='fro')**2
    ratios.append(lhs/rhs)

print(np.max(ratios))
```

After a little literature search,
it seems that a slightly modified version of the inequality,
with a factor $1/2$ instead of $1/4$ in the right-hand side,
is a consequence of Theorem IX.4.2 in the textbook *Matrix Analysis* by Rajendra Bhatia.

**Statement** of Theorem IX.4.2: for any two matrices,
$$s_j(A^*B) \leq \frac{1}{2} \, s_j(AA^* + BB^*),$$
where $s_j$, $j = 1, \dots, n$, denotes the $j$-th singular value.

**Proof** that this partially answers the question: we can rewrite the left-hand side as
$$
GM(A, B) := tr \left( (A B^2 A)^{1/2}\right) = tr \left(\left((BA)^*BA\right)^{1/2} \right) = \sum_j s_j(BA).
$$
Using the quoted result, we therefore obtain
\begin{align}
GM(A, B) &\leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_j s_j(A^2 + B^2) = \frac{1}{2} tr(A^2 + B^2) \\
&= \frac 14 tr((A + B)^2 + (A - B)^2) \\
&= \frac 14 tr(A + B)^2 + \frac{1}{4} tr(A - B)^2 \\
&= \frac 14 \|A + B\|_F^2 + \frac 14 \|A - B\|_F^2 \\
&\leq \frac 12 \|A + B\|_F^2 =: 2 \, AM(A, B).
\end{align}
Let us note that numerical experiments show that
the inequality
$$
\frac{1}{2} \sum_j s_j(A^2 + B^2) \leq 2 \, AM(A, B),
$$
is sharp.

Comment: Your observation that it holds for diagonal $A$ and $B$ can be easily extended to the claim that the inequality holds when $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: @angryavian yes, indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this question is non-trivial and was resolved only in 1999, by Rajendra Bhatia and Fuad Kittaneh in the paper *Notes on matrix arithmetic–geometric mean inequalities*, freely available [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379500000483). They show that, for any unitarily invariant matrix norm $\|.\|$,
$$
\| A B\|\leq \frac 14 \|(A+B)^2\|.
$$
In the particular case of the [Schatten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) norm with $p = 1$,
this means
$$
\sum_j s_j(AB) \leq \frac{1}{4} \sum_j s_j ((A + B)^2) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_j (s_j(A+B))^2,
$$
which is the inequality we were trying to show.

Answer (score -1):

Denote $C = AB$, then $CC^t$ is positive definite. Hence,

$$ tr \left( (A B^2 A)^{1/2} \right) = tr \left( (CC^t)^{1/2} \right)  \leq  \left( tr(CC^t) \right)^{1/2} = \left( tr (A B^2 A)\right)^{1/2} = \left( tr (A^2 B^2 )\right)^{1/2} = tr(AB).$$

Now,

$$ tr(AB) = \sum_i \sum_j a_{i,j} b_{j,i} \leq \sum_i \sum_j \frac{1}{4}(a_{i,j} + b_{j,i})^2 = \sum_i \sum_j \frac{1}{4}(a_{i,j} + b_{i,j})^2 = \frac{1}{4} \| A + B\|_F^2.$$

Hence the result

Comment: You're claiming $(\operatorname{tr}(A^2B^2))^{1/2}=\operatorname{tr}(AB)$? That doesn't even work for simultaneously diagonalise $A,\,B$. I think you meant $(\operatorname{tr}(A^2B^2))^{1/2}\le\operatorname{tr}(AB)$.

Comment: The inequality $tr \left( (CC^t)^{1/2} \right)  \leq  \left( tr(CC^t) \right)^{1/2}$ also isn't correct. E.g. when $C=I_2$, the inequality gives $2\le\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You are both correct!

Comment: I would add that it is in fact not true that $tr( (AB^2A)^{1/2}) \leq tr(AB)$. I don't have a counter-example here but it's clear from a numerical test.